# What is the best structure JSON structure for a multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have the following excel table.
I would like to represent that table in a json structure.

What is the best structure for that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the JSON Structure. Please check and confirm.

```
  {
    "men": [
      {
        "USA": [
          {
            "during12months": {
              "1997": "9.5%",
              "2002": "16.6%",
              "2012": "12.2%"
            },
            "earlier12months": {
              "1997": "8.3%",
              "2002": "7.8%",
              "2012": "22.9%"
            },
            "never": {
              "1997": "82.2%",
              "2002": "75.6%",
              "2012": "64.9%"
            }
          }
        ],
        "Europe": [
          {
            "during12months": {
              "1997": "9.2%",
              "2002": "14.4%",
              "2012": "13.7%"
            },
            "earlier12months": {
              "1997": "11.3%",
              "2002": "8.2%",
              "2012": "18.5%"
            },
            "never": {
              "1997": "79.5%",
              "2002": "77.4%",
              "2012": "67.8%"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "women": [
      {
        "USA": [
          {
            "during12months": {
              "1997": "12.1%",
              "2002": "15.5%",
              "2012": "13.4%"
            },
            "earlier12months": {
              "1997": "7.0%",
              "2002": "8.4%",
              "2012": "23.6%"
            },
            "never": {
              "1997": "80.9%",
              "2002": "76.1%",
              "2012": "63.0%"
            }
          }
        ],
        "Europe": [
          {
            "during12months": {
              "1997": "12.6%",
              "2002": "17.6%",
              "2012": "14.9%"
            },
            "earlier12months": {
              "1997": "8.8%",
              "2002": "8.2%",
              "2012": "16.9%"
            },
            "never": {
              "1997": "78.6%",
              "2002": "74.2%",
              "2012": "68.2%"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "total": [
      {
        "USA": [
          {
            "during12months": {
              "1997": "10.8%",
              "2002": "16.0%",
              "2012": "12.8%"
            },
            "earlier12months": {
              "1997": "7.7%",
              "2002": "8.1%",
              "2012": "23.3%"
            },
            "never": {
              "1997": "81.5%",
              "2002": "75.9%",
              "2012": "63.9%"
            }
          }
        ],
        "Europe": [
          {
            "during12months": {
              "1997": "11.0%",
              "2002": "16.0%",
              "2012": "14.3%"
            },
            "earlier12months": {
              "1997": "10.0%",
              "2002": "8.2%",
              "2012": "17.7%"
            },
            "never": {
              "1997": "79.0%",
              "2002": "75.8%",
              "2012": "68.0%"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

To get the query with the column:

```
{
  "men": [
    { 
      "Europe": [
        {

          "earlier12months": {
            "1997": "11.3%",
            "2002": "8.2%",
            "2012": "18.5%"
          }

        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "women": [
    {

      "Europe": [
        {

          "earlier12months": {
            "1997": "8.8%",
            "2002": "8.2%",
            "2012": "16.9%"
          }

        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "total": [
    {

      "Europe": [
        {

          "earlier12months": {
            "1997": "10.0%",
            "2002": "8.2%",
            "2012": "17.7%"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it will help you

Thanks
Muthu

Comment: thanks, what about if i want to query the column "europe", "earlier than 2months". Is that possible ?

Comment: @stephone  I have edited the above post. Please check and confirm, If u satisfied by my post please vote my answer

Answer (score 2):

Best structure? It depends. One way is to create an array of objects (cells). Each cell containing properties like "percentage", "country", "sex" and "year". That way you would be able to sort these columns easily.

Another way is to create the 2d array of cells with just X and Y properties to show their position in a table. You will have to send some info about the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

for Harder version .. LOL !

[image]

Source:

```
{
 "rows": 
[
{ row:"Men", 
data:{ rows:[
{ row:"1997",data:{ 
cols:[ 
{ col:"USA", data: { 
cols:[ 
{ col:"during last 12", data:"9.5%"},
{ col:"earlier than 12", data:"9.5%"},
{ col:"never", data:"9.5%"} ] }}
,
{ col:"Europe", data: {}}] } },
{ row:"2002",data:{} },
{ row:"2002",data:{} }]  }}
,
{ row:"Women" }
,
{ row:"Total" }
]
}
```

Be funny.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit upon the "it depends" from another answer (Seeing as this seems to be the only time a question like this has been asked, according to google).

It seems to me like a sensible default option for representing multidimensional data is something along the lines of:

```
[
  { 
    "sex": "female", 
    "region": "europe", 
    "year": 2012, 
    "interval": "never", 
    "value": 12.5
  }
]
```

This way, every value-object knows its place in the coordinate space, and "all" queries are equally simple to implement. Perhaps performance will be worse than if the data is organized in a way where specific queries are cheaper, but leave that optimization until it is needed.